# Responding to model changes in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, model, django-signals

Is there a way to execute code when a model change happens? How might I observe when a Django model object is added, deleted, or edited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [django-signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/signals/) are for. You can user `post_save` and `post_delete` to observe model objects.

> Django provides a set of built-in signals that let user code get notified by Django itself of certain actions.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import MyModel

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    # do whatever you want if a MyModel object is saved
```

Answer (score 1):

Django [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/) are perfect for this. Similar to NSNotificationCenter on iOS, Django signals allow for other apps to be notified of signalled events by connecting to a signal.